# How to aviod rubberband become a a line and How to set rubberband only show border line?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I write a simple app, While drag or scale the `MainView`, The `PartView` rubberband will show      scene area in `PartView`.But sometime the rubber-band become a line, and sometime the rubberband disappear.So How to aviod this phenomenon appear?And sometime I want the rubberband only show it's border-line, not contain it's light-blue rectangle,So how can I write code ?

**My Code**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import random
import math

r = lambda : random.randint(0, 255)
r255 = lambda : (r(), r(), r())

class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for i in range(1000):
            item = QGraphicsEllipseItem()
            item.setRect(0, 0, r(), r())
            item.setBrush(QColor(*r255()))
            item.setPos(r()*100, r()*100)
            self.addItem(item)

class MainView(QGraphicsView):
    sigExposeRect = pyqtSignal(QRectF)
    def drawBackground(self, painter: QPainter, rect: QRectF) -> None:
        super().drawBackground(painter, rect)
        self.sigExposeRect.emit(rect)

    def wheelEvent(self, event: QWheelEvent) -> None:
        factor = math.pow(2.7, event.angleDelta().y()/360)
        self.scale(factor, factor)

class PartView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.r = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.r.setWindowOpacity(1)
        self.r.show()

class View(QSplitter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.m = MainView()
        self.m.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.m.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.m.sigExposeRect.connect(self.onExposeRect)

        self.p = PartView()

        self.m.setScene(Scene())
        self.p.setScene(self.m.scene())
        self.p.fitInView(self.m.scene().itemsBoundingRect())

        self.addWidget(self.m)
        self.addWidget(self.p)

    def onExposeRect(self, rect: QRectF):
        prect = self.p.mapFromScene(rect).boundingRect()
        self.p.r.setGeometry(prect)

app = QApplication([])
v = View()
v.show()
app.exec()
```

**My Result**
[image]

Comment: Those are two very different questions (remember that each post should only have one question). For the contents color, try with a basic stylesheet using the `selection-background-color` property with `transparent`. For the other part, it's a bit unclear what you're actually doing here: why are you using the drawBackground? If you're trying to display the currently exposed area of the scene, that's *not* the way to do that.

Comment: The `unclear`  is I need get exposed area of the scene and then emit to another view.I had re-write it in `scrollContentsBy` to get exposed area of the scene.

Comment: `selection-background-color` is not right, I want show outline(border line) in `QRubberBand`, Maybe I should try other method.

Comment: The `selection-background-color` is *exactly* for that (setting the background to transparent), but it's *not* guaranteed to work, though, as painting of QRubberBand is completely style based, so the only way to achieve a reliable painting is by overriding the rubber band `paintEvent` or completely remove it and do that on the target graphics view.

Comment: But I don't know how to draw a border-line use `paintEvent ` method, Use `QWidget` to draw border-line I think it will be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `qrect` passed to the `drawBackground` method is only includes the portion of the background that wasn't previously in the viewport.  Not positive about that though.

Either way I was able to achieve your goal of avoiding only a section of the rubber band being drawn, by sending the area for the entire viewport to the `onExposeRect` slot.

```py
class MainView(QGraphicsView):
    sigExposeRect = pyqtSignal(QRectF)
    def drawBackground(self, painter: QPainter, rect: QRectF) -> None:
        # Adding this next line was the only change I made
        orect = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().geometry()).boundingRect() 
        super().drawBackground(painter, rect)
        self.sigExposeRect.emit(orect)  # and passing it to the slot.

    def wheelEvent(self, event: QWheelEvent) -> None:
        factor = math.pow(2.7, event.angleDelta().y()/360)
        self.scale(factor, factor)
```

Comment: You are right, your idea is same as me.Why?For I waiting for you to answer the question.

Comment: That's exactly the problem I was referring to in my comment: Graphics View uses extended optimizations to get maximum performance, so painting doesn't always include the *whole* exposed area. On the contrary, most of the times it only draws a relatively small portion of the scene (for items that *do* need repainting). Hence, it is *not* reliable for this purpose.

Comment: @alexpdev Yes, I know, but it's still prone to issues based on performance optimization of the view, since `drawBackground` could be called very often even if the exposed rect is always the same (or could not be called at all under certain situations!); it also doesn't consider the scrolling of the target view, so the rubberband will always stay in the same position even when its view is scrolled.

Comment: @alexpdev I'm not saying you shouldn't post an answer, but if I see that a solution has some issues I feel important to point them out (both to the author and to any reader). If I believe that those issues are severe, then I might downvote (which I didn't, in this case), but I rarely do that for answers, unless they are *very* bad ones, as I prefer to leave their authors the time to eventually fix them.

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental aspect about Graphics View is its high performance in drawing even thousands of elements.

To achieve this, one of the most important optimization is updating only the portions of the scene that really need redrawing, similar to what item views do, as they normally only redraw the items that *actually* require updates, instead of *always* painting the whole visible area, which can be a huge bottleneck.

This is the reason for which overriding `drawBackground` is ineffective: sometimes, only a small portion of the scene is updated (and, in certain situations, even *no* update is done at all), and the `rect` argument of `drawBackground` only includes *that* portion, not the whole visible area. The result is that in these situations, the signal will emit a rectangle that will not be consistent with the visible area.

Since the visible area is relative to the *viewport* of the scroll area, the only safe way to receive updates about that area is to connect to the horizontal and vertical scroll bars (which always work even if they are hidden).

A further precaution is to ensure that the visible rectangle is also updated whenever the scene rect is changed (since that change might not be reflected by the scroll bars), by connecting to the [`sceneRectChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRectChanged) signal and also overriding the [`setSceneRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop) of the source view. Considering that the changes in vertical and scroll bars might coincide, it's usually a good idea to delay the signal with a 0-delay QTimer, so that it's only sent once when more changes to the visible area happen at the same time.

Note that since you're not actually using the features of QRubberBand, there's little use in its usage, especially if you also need custom painting. Also, since the rubber band is a child of the view, it will always keep its position even if the preview view is scrolled.

In the following example I'll show two ways of drawing the "fake" rubber band (but choose only one of them, either comment one or the other to test them) that will always be consistent with both the source and target views.

```
class MainView(QGraphicsView):
    sigExposeRect = pyqtSignal(QRectF)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.signalDelay = QTimer(self, singleShot=True, interval=0, 
            timeout=self.emitExposeRect)
        # signals might have arguments that collide with the start(interval)
        # override of QTimer, let's use a basic lambda that ignores them
        self.delayEmit = lambda *args: self.signalDelay.start()
        self.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.delayEmit)
        self.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.delayEmit)

    def emitExposeRect(self):
        topLeft = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().geometry().topLeft())
        bottomRight = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().geometry().bottomRight())
        self.sigExposeRect.emit(QRectF(topLeft, bottomRight))

    def setScene(self, scene):
        if self.scene() == scene:
            return
        if self.scene():
            try:
                self.scene().sceneRectChanged.disconnect(self.delayEmit)
            except TypeError:
                pass
        super().setScene(scene)
        if scene:
            scene.sceneRectChanged.connect(self.delayEmit)

    def setSceneRect(self, rect):
        super().setSceneRect(rect)
        self.delayEmit()

    def wheelEvent(self, event: QWheelEvent) -> None:
        factor = math.pow(2.7, event.angleDelta().y()/360)
        self.scale(factor, factor)


class PartView(QGraphicsView):
    exposeRect = None
    def updateExposeRect(self, rect):
        if self.exposeRect != rect:
            self.exposeRect = rect
            self.viewport().update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if not self.exposeRect:
            return
        rect = self.mapFromScene(self.exposeRect).boundingRect()

        # use either *one* of the following:

        # 1. QStyle implementation, imitates QRubberBand
        qp = QStylePainter(self.viewport())
        opt = QStyleOptionRubberBand()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        opt.rect = rect
        qp.drawControl(QStyle.CE_RubberBand, opt)

        # 2. basic QPainter
        qp = QPainter(self.viewport())
        color = self.palette().highlight().color()
        qp.setPen(self.palette().highlight().color())
        # for background
        bgd = QColor(color)
        bgd.setAlpha(40)
        qp.setBrush(bgd)
        qp.drawRect(rect)


class View(QSplitter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.m = MainView()
        self.m.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.m.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

        self.p = PartView()

        self.m.setScene(Scene())
        self.p.setScene(self.m.scene())
        self.p.fitInView(self.m.scene().itemsBoundingRect())

        self.addWidget(self.m)
        self.addWidget(self.p)

        self.m.sigExposeRect.connect(self.p.updateExposeRect)
```

<sup>PS: please use single letter variables when they actually make sense (common variables, coordinates, loop placeholders, etc.), not for complex objects, and especially for attributes: there's no benefit in using `self.m` or `self.p`, and the only result you get is to make code less readable to you and others.</sup>